# BeautifulSoup does not return all elements on page

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to Web scraping and just started using BeautifulSoup. Here's my question.

When you look up a word in Google in such a way using a search query like "define:lucid", in most cases, a panel showing the meaning and the pronunciation appears at the front page. (Shown in the left side of the embedded image)

**[Google default dictionary example]**

[image]

Things I want to scrape and collect automatically are the text of the meaning and the URL in which the mp3 data of the pronunciation is stored. Using the Chrome Inspector manually, these are easily found in its "Elements" section, e.g., the Inspector (shown in the right side of the image) shows the URL, which stores the mp3 data of the pronunciation of "lucid" ([here](https://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/oxford/lucid--_gb_1.mp3)).

However, using requests to get the content of the HTML of the search result and parsing it with BeautifulSoup, like the code below, the `soup` gets only a few of contents in the panel such as the IPA "/ˈluːsɪd/" and the attribute "adjective" like the result below, and none of the contents I need can be found, such as things in audio elements.

How can I get the information with BeautifulSoup if possible, otherwise what alternative tools are suitable for this task?

P.S. I think the quality of pronunciation from Google dictionary is better than ones from any other dictionary sites. So I want to stick to it.

Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

query = "define:lucid"
goog_search = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + query

r = requests.get(goog_search)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Part of `soup` content:

```
           </span>
           <span style="font:smaller 'Doulos SIL','Gentum','TITUS Cyberbit Basic','Junicode','Aborigonal Serif','Arial Unicode MS','Lucida Sans Unicode','Chrysanthi Unicode';padding-left:15px">
            /ˈluːsɪd/
           </span>
          </div>
         </h3>
         <table style="font-size:14px;width:100%">
          <tr>
           <td>
            <div style="color:#666;padding:5px 0">
             adjective
            </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic request you run is not returning the parts of the page rendered via JavaScript. If you right-click in Chrome and select View Page Source the audio link is not there. Solution: you could render the page via `selenium`. With the below code I get the `<audio>` tag including the link.

You'll have to `pip install selenium`, download [ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.32/) and add the folder containing it to `PATH` like `export PATH=$PATH:~/downloads/`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium import webdriver

def render_page(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    r = driver.page_source
    #driver.quit()
    return r

query = "define:lucid"
goog_search = "https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=" + query

r = render_page(goog_search)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())
```

Comment: The solution works perfectly for both of the missing audio file and text of the meaning.

Comment: Great to hear! Can you accept the answer/upvote if it was helpful? Thanks and good luck!

Comment: The upvote is not displayed right now because my reputation is less than 15 lol. The reason I don't still accept the answer is I want to get the page content without opening the actual browser. And the reason I didn't mention this in the last comment was I thought I should have tried something from [this](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/running-webdriver-without-opening-actual-browser-window) first by myself.

Comment: OK, sure. You could try replacing `webdriver.Chrome()` with `webdriver.PhantomJS()`. You will have to install PhantomJS first to make this work and add it to `PATH`. It is a headless browser, so everything will run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

I checked it. You're right, in the BeautifulSoup output there is no audio elements for some reason. However, having inspected the code, I found a source for the audio file which Google is using, which is http://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/oxford/lucid--_gb_1.mp3 and which perfectly works if you substitute "lucid" with any other word.

So, if you need to scrape the audio file, you could just do the following:

```
url='http://ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/oxford/'    
audio=requests.get(url+'lucid'+'--_gb_1.mp3', stream=True).content
with open('lucid'+'.mp3', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(audio)
```

As for other elements, I'm afraid you'll need just to find the word "definition" in the soup and scrape the content of the tag that contains it.

Comment: The solution is clever. Knowing some variation of words which is stored with the trailing "_gb_1.8" like "inculpate" or the leading "x" like "conspicuous", I get hundreds of the audio file of words.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need in `selenium` to slow down scraping time as [M3RS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46114500/15164646) shows since the data is in the HTML, not rendered via JavaScript. Have a look at the [SelectorsGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to grab `CSS` selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser.

You're looking for this (`CSS` selectors [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)):

```py
soup.select_one('audio source')['src']
# //ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20200429/swagger--_gb_1.mp3
```

Make sure you're using [`user-agent`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) because default `requests` `user-agent` is [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814) thus Google blocks a request because it knows that it's a bot and not a "real" user visit and you'll receive a different HTML with some sort of an error. user-agent faking user visit by adding this information into [HTTP request headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers).

---

Code:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, lxml

headers = {
    'User-agent':
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582'
}

params = {
  'q': 'lucid definition',
  'hl': 'en',
}

html = requests.get('https://www.google.com/search', headers=headers, params=params)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, 'lxml')

phonetic = soup.select_one('.S23sjd .LTKOO span').text
audio_link = soup.select_one('audio source')['src']
print(phonetic)
print(audio_link)

# ˈluːsɪd
# //ssl.gstatic.com/dictionary/static/sounds/20200429/swagger--_us_1.mp3
```

---

Alternatively, you can achieve the same thing by using [Google Direct Answer Box API](https://serpapi.com/direct-answer-box-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan.

The difference in your case is that you only need to grab the data you want fast, instead of coding everything from scratch, figuring out why certain things don't work as they should, and then maintain it over time if something in the HTML layout is changed.

*At the moment, SerpApi doesn't extract audio link. This will be changed in the future. Please, check it in the [playground](https://serpapi.com/playground?q=swagger%20definition&gl=us&hl=en) to clarify if the audio link is present.*

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "api_key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "lucid definition",
  "hl": "en"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

phonetic = results['answer_box']['syllables']
print(phonetic)

# lu·cid
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.